# Installing applications

Tags: windows-7

I am having a problem installing applications on Windows 7.  I keep getting the error

> This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

I have downloaded the right packages for iTunes and Google Earth but they just wont install

Comment: Do the event logs give you more information? Can you create a log file with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and check if there are ACCESS DENIED (just CTRL+F for DENIED) events (or upload so we can check for anything that's weird)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on a recently built machine (Win 7 64-bit) and it turned out to be faulty RAM - the machine was generally stable with the odd glitch, which I put down to not having all the system board drivers installed yet, but it really started to behave badly when I ran any installers. The fix was to replace the RAM.

Comment: Ive checked both pieces of RAm and they have no problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of Windows 7 you are using - 32 bit or 64 bit.

Make sure that you download the correct architecture version of the installer. If you are on 32 bit Windows make sure you install the 32 bit version of the application. It shouldn't matter which one you install if you are on 64 bit Windows, but it would be better to install the 64 bit version.

Given that you've checked and installed these then the next obvious thing is that the download is corrupt. Re-download the installer and try again. It seems unlikely that two installers would be affected in the same way though.

Comment: Am using a 64 bit, which is what i donwload, nothing seems to work. ihave made sure i have downloaded for the correct architecture

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a [new version of the Windows Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4), but they don't seem to be available for Windows 7.

Or you could try to go through this [knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651#reso1).

Comment: Which would be for windows 7, I have tried them but none is working

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

My guess out of the blue, Downloaded and directly started from Firefox, did you leave FF open? - cause it will remove temp files when closed.

Comment: I downloaded from one machine and then went to install on another